# Unable to push struct that contains an array of structs to an array

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm aware there are some limitations on initializing empty arrays, but I can't find a solution to this issue I'm having.

I want to push a struct to an array. But since that struct itself contains an array of other structs, I'm unable to do it.

Here's my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;



contract simpleBet {

    struct Bettor {
        address wallet;
        uint betAmount;
        uint outcome;
        uint bettingTime;
    }

    struct bettingEvent {
        string name;
        string uid;
        uint startTime;
        uint endTime;
        Bettor[] bettors;
    }

    bettingEvent[] public bettingEvents;

    constructor() public {
    }


    function createBettingEvent(string _name, string _uid, uint _startTime, uint _endTime) public {

        bettingEvent memory _bettingEvent;
        _bettingEvent.name = _name;
        _bettingEvent.uid = _uid;
        _bettingEvent.startTime = _startTime;
        _bettingEvent.endTime = _endTime;
        _bettingEvent.bettors.push(Bettor(0,0,0,0));


        bettingEvents.push(_bettingEvent);
    }

}
```

> TypeError: Member "push" is not available in struct simpleBet.Bettor memory[] memory outside of storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you can't `push` to arrays that are located in memory. (Such arrays are not resizable.)

One possible fix is to just do the changes in storage:

```
function createBettingEvent(string _name, string _uid, uint _startTime, uint _endTime) public {
    bettingEvents.length += 1;
    bettingEvent storage _bettingEvent = bettingEvents[bettingEvents.length - 1];
    _bettingEvent.name = _name;
    _bettingEvent.uid = _uid;
    _bettingEvent.startTime = _startTime;
    _bettingEvent.endTime = _endTime;
    _bettingEvent.bettors.push(Bettor(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that, but still get the error: `UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct simpleBet.Bettor memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.
`

Comment: I don't get that error on Remix. Can you update the question with the full latest source code so I can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I do see that error in the compiler output; Remix just didn't surface it in the editor UI for some reason. Taking a look.

Comment: Edited with working code. Surely there's a cleaner way to do that, but this works.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I've just noticed your username. I'm playing capturethether, it's awesome!

Btw, I know it's off the scope of the op, but should I use mapping instead of the array to make it cleaner?

Comment: Glad you're enjoying Capture the Ether. :-) Yeah, I wonder if a `mapping` might be better. Mappings and arrays are remarkably similar. See the "Queue" section of https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/23/storage-patterns-stacks-queues-and-deques/ for a spot where I used a `mapping` instead of an array.

Comment: @smarx What actually this line is doing? bettingEvent storage _bettingEvent = bettingEvents[bettingEvents.length - 1];

Comment: It's declaring a local variable named `_bettingEvent`, which is a reference to a `bettingEvent` `struct` located in storage. It's then assigning that variable a reference to the last element of the `bettingEvents` array.